# Connect to Azure VM (Windows) from Ubuntu

Tags: azure

As per title, I would like to connect to Azure VM (Windows) from my Ubuntu machine. xrdp requires that I know the VM's IP address, which I don't know. When I connect to Azure VM from Windows machine, I only need to put the workspace URL `https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com` and my Azure auth.

Is there anything similar in Ubuntu?

Comment: You are referring to Azure Virtual Desktop, not the usual Azure Windows VM. Thus, the only Microsoft supported way for Linux users is to use the web client, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/users/connect-web Third party might develop a Linux native client (not likely xrdp) but you will need to use a search engine.